# Cookie not sent when with request

Tags: django, reactjs, cookies, django-rest-framework, fetch-api

I am pretty new to web development with API. So I have a function that send a request to the server with the code below. It get sent along with a token that I store in cookie.

```
var myHeaders = new Headers();
        myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
        myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "text/plain");

        var raw = "{\n    \"latitude\": \"69.23489236336972000\",\n    \"longitude\": \"-69.08944702148439000\",\n    \"log_start\": \"2020-05-03T09:37:41Z\",\n    \"log_end\": \"2020-05-03T10:00:00Z\"\n}";

        var requestOptions = {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: myHeaders,
            body: raw,
            redirect: 'follow',
            credentials: 'include',
        };

        fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/logs/log/", requestOptions)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(result => console.log(result))
            .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

**However, I keep getting this error when I try to send it.**


https://i.stack.imgur.com/StU0q.png


**After a bit digging, I notice that my cookie is not being sent with the request (as shown by the picture below). This is pretty odd to me because I set "credentials" to "include" in the requestOptions.**


https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hp1mi.png

**However, when I comment out lines that append "Content-Type" to header so that the header becomes empty. The cookie is included in the header again, along with other headers that were not included in the first place.**

```
var myHeaders = new Headers();
        // myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
        // myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "text/plain");

        var raw = "{\n    \"latitude\": \"69.23489236336972000\",\n    \"longitude\": \"-69.08944702148439000\",\n    \"log_start\": \"2020-05-03T09:37:41Z\",\n    \"log_end\": \"2020-05-03T10:00:00Z\"\n}";

        var requestOptions = {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: myHeaders,
            body: raw,
            redirect: 'follow',
            credentials: 'include',
        };

        fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/logs/log/", requestOptions)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(result => console.log(result))
            .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJNbB.png


**But if I don't set "Content-Type" to "application/json", I would receive "415 Unsupported Media Type" error.**


Does anyone have any idea why is this? And how to fix it?

Thank you in advance.



I don't have enough reputations to post images so I have attached them as url

Answer (score 0):

For starters, I would advice setup cors policy for your server, because when you set Content-Type you get this error
When you don't set Content-Type you put into payload application/json type but actualy your Content-Type: plain/text. So, maybe you server on this request can only work with json data, not text, so you get error. But these are just my assumptions

Comment: Thanks. I kinda have to changed my server settings to make this work.

Answer (score 0):

### Update

I forgot to update this, but I have found the solution for this. Cookies are not supposed to be sent in preflights. In your backend, you have to grant permission to preflights (specifically, HTTP OPTIONS). In my case, I use Django with django-rest-framework so my example solution would look like.

```py
class PreflightsOnly(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        return request.method == "OPTIONS"


class LogAPI(generics.GenericAPIView):

    queryset = Log.objects.all()
    permission_classes = [PreflightsOnly|permissions.IsAuthenticated]
    serializer_class = LogSerializer
```

### Comment on May 5

I still don't have a reason why this happens. However, I have a work-around that allows me to make it work.

What I did was that I decided to no set a "Content-Type" in the header at all. So I had to stick with the default "Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8". So to make this work, I made a custom parser that accepted this "Content-Type".

```
from rest_framework.parsers import BaseParser
import ast

class PlainTextParser(BaseParser):

    """
    Plain text parser.
    """
    media_type = 'text/plain;charset=UTF-8'

    def parse(self, stream, media_type=None, parser_context=None):
        """
        Simply return a string representing the body of the request.
        """
        byte_str = stream.read()
        dict_str = byte_str.decode("UTF-8")
        data = ast.literal_eval(dict_str)

        return data
```

Then inside "settings.py" of my Django app, I setup REST_FRAMEWORK DEFAULT_PARSER_CLASSES like this:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    ...,
    'DEFAULT_PARSER_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework_customs.parsers.PlainTextParser',
    ]
}
```